# How to run a PWA in a Intranet without a trusted SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, progressive-web-apps

I'm setting up a Intranet environment to run a PWA for business purposes in future. But I encountered a problem regarding SSL certificates.

In my plan:

- Everything is on a local network (maybe with no internet access), with a dedicated server in it (i'm using ubuntu server),
- the user access the main page with a computer or phone, in which he install a PWA on his device.

PWA needs HTTPS to work, and I can self-sign certificates (i'm doing it for testing), but it's not a solution for implementating the app because it generate a **security error** on every browser on the planet with this method.

Importing certificates to browser is not a solution for me because it's a hassle to import the certificate on every user browser (it isn't user friendly), also it's impossible in android without root.

I'm wanting to create a PWA that needs the minimum advanced user help to work, so importing certificates and doing work-arounds is a no no.

Its possible to run a PWA without this certificate problem or I should drop it and begin a standard web app for now ?

Comment: [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) exists. Use it. Stop self-signing certificates and expecting people to just click-through ignore the important security warnings, that builds super bad habits. Expecting people to install some sketchy self-signed certificate is likewise really not a solution. Let's Encrypt does require a connection, but you can generate the cert in one location and deploy it on another protected behind a firewall if the DNS names match.

Comment: This doesn't work because the server doens't have a public domain name, i'm running it on a server on the same network. I'm currently accessing it via IP only.

Comment: You can set up local DNS to make it work. Accessing by IP is a problem here, you need a name.

Comment: did you find a solution @Viníciuspereira ?

Comment: I have the exact same situation, need to run pwa on employee mobile devices, server hosted on lan. Client dont want to use app by workers if not present around workplace.

Comment: @tadman Let's Encrypt will not issue certificates for hostnames under domain names reserved for internal use.

Comment: Well, first of all, I guess no one knows difference between intranet and internet. They think it's a typo by asker 

Answer (score 1):

The PWA needs to be hosted on a secure server, but it can communicate with non-secure services. A possible workaround is:

- Host the PWA on a secure site, shouldn't cost much if anything (ex. AWS)
- Secure site is basically only used for hosting the app and updates
- Communicate with your non-secure service on your LAN within the PWA

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best option is to purchase a cheap domain that you can use for this.

Then, use internal DNS for the network to point the domain name to your internal server (public can just stay as the default parked page, or whatever you like).

Then, use certbot with the --manual flag to generate a free cert - https://certbot.eff.org/

You'll need to verify DNS to get the trusted SSL from Lets Encrypt via certbot - which is why you need DNS.

As others have mentioned, you could also buy a cheap SSL (if you don't want to mess with certbot).

Answer (score -2):

HTTPS is a core requirement for running a PWA.
Certificates are no longer that expensive.
Just figure that into your yearly hosting costs.
Until you get your HTTPS running with a cert, perhaps you could use something like https://glitch.com/ for free testing

Comment: I'm hosting the app myself on a server that is on the same network as me, so I don't a public domain name, i'm currently accessing it via IP only.

Comment: OK. You could still use Glitch for free to test your PWA code on HTTPS if needed.