# Angular 9 Service Worker not working when serving site from S3 Static Website

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm building a PWA application, so I:

- Create a new Angular app as usual (CLI 9.1.8);
- Added PWA support as per doc (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started);
- Built it with `ng build --prod`;
- Copied it to S3 bucket that is configured to serve a static website;
- Browsed it on Chrome with success.

Problem is:

- Event `beforeinstallprompt` never gets fired;
- Developer Tools -> Application never says there is a Service Worker registed for this site.

On the other hand, if I serve it locally (say `http-server dist/my-app`) and browse it on Chrome, it works just fine, with `beforeinstallprompt`, Service Worker and everything else.

However, similarly to what happens when I browse it on S3 Static Website, it does not fully work if I use my iPhone/Android to browse the app served on my desktop using WI-FI network. I know that iOS does not support `beforeinstallprompt` event but neither it happens on Android too.

May it not be a problem with serving PWA from S3 Static Website but instead with my very app? Maybe I'm missing a step or whatever.

So, to summarize: It works only when serving the app from `localhost` and browsing in on Chrome running on the same machine.

**Note:** Not sure if this matters or not but I'm not using AWS Amplify at this point. Probably in the future but not yet. Is this required to serve PWA from S3 Static Website?

Comment: I just realized now that if I browse the local served on Chrome using WI-FI ip (some 192.168.15.3 kind of thing), it does not work as per what happens to S3 and iPhone. So it only works when browsing on localhost address.

Comment: HTTPS? I think that is it...

Comment: Yes, I do think so. I generated a cert and used on my http-server; browsed the PWA from desktop IP and got: "Service worker registration failed with: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://192.168.12.3:8080/') with script ('https://192.168.12.3:8080/ngsw-worker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script." - WITHOUT HTTPS, it does not fire service worker registration.

Comment: Okay. I am a dumb newbie. HTTPS is a must for proper PWA. (1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs and (2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676452/7822700

Comment: did you figure this out on localhost yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. As per my previous comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is a must for PWA check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs

One way of setting up HTTP is to set up cloudfront with your s3bucket just remember to check option HTTP to HTTPS while